# Problema de codificación al mostrar información de una base de datos

Tags: php

Antes que nada muchas gracias por leerme.

Soy muy nuevo en php y en html. Estoy modificando una pagina en php (como puedo me las arreglo) y tengo que hacer una tabla para mostrar información en dicha tabla para poder eliminar registros desde la pagina. Ya tengo la tabla hecha pero me surgió un problema, me muestra información con caracteres `�`. Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Les dejo una foto como ejemplo esto es en casi todos los campos que llevan mucha información:
[image: Es esta]

Les agradecería mucho si me ayudan.

Comment: Utiliza la función mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8") luego de hacer la conexión con la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente sea por el header del `Content-Type`.

Desde PHP añade lo siguiente al principio del archivo usando [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

También puedes chequearlo desde el html con el tag [`meta`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/meta):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```